# how to bring ajax sorted result into html divs

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

HI i have done some `AJAX`, PHP&MySQL Sorting and it is giving me result in tables as shown in the code below, my question is **how to bring that $result in html `divs`.**

please help

**PHP code used**

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("security_software", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM internet_security ORDER by '".$q."' DESC" ;


$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>title</th>
<th>image</th>
<th>description</th>
<th>rating</th>
<th>download</th>
<th>buy</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['image'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['rating'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['download'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['buy'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**I want Result In These HTML Div's**

```
<div class="category-container">
    <div class="category-image"></div>
    <div class="category-link"><a href="#">#</a></div>
    <div class="category-desc"><p>#</p> </div>          
    <div class="rating5" >Editors' rating: </div>        
    <div class="category-download-btn"><a href="#">Download </a></div><
    <div class="category-buy-btn"><a href="#">Buy</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: why do you create table as ajax response? instead use json format or use the format in which you want the o/p. Simple.

Comment: actually i was looking a way to sort data and everywhere it is explained in tables, so i implemented it, and it's workin fine, i just want the result to be diaplayed in html divs, sorting method i have used has two pages, one is the main page and other to get query, html divs are on one page and these table on another, i hope you got it

Comment: I have updated code if you want to use. And yes using the same json you can create tables also. Thank you

Comment: yes please provide me the codes, i am learning to use json now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inclined to view this as a bit of a joke, seeing as the database is called "security_software", and you're putting a GET var directly into a database query without doing any sanitation. You're also making no attempt to clean anything coming from the database before spitting it back onto the page...

Anyway, assuming it's not a joke, the following should point you in the right direction:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("security_software", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM internet_security ORDER by '".$q."' DESC" ;

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<div class="category-image"><img src="' $row['image'] . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="category-link"><a href="#">' . $row['title'] . '</a></div>';
    echo '<div class="category-desc"><p>' . $row['description'] . '</p></div>';        
    echo '<div class="rating5" >Editors' rating: ' . $row['rating'] . '</div>';       
    echo '<div class="category-download-btn"><a href="' . $row['download'] .'">Download</a></div>';
    echo '<div class="category-buy-btn"><a href="' . $row['buy'] . '">Buy</a></div>';
 }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are creating table when returning the ajax response. I advice you to create json response as a result of ajax. Using this result JSON you can either create table or you can render them in your html.
in your php code where ajax request is sent: ajax.php

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("security_software", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM internet_security ORDER by '".$q."' DESC" ;


$result = mysql_query($sql);
$response = array();
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $response[$i]['id']           =$row['id'];
  $response[$i]['title']        = $row['title'];
  $response[$i]['image']        = $row['image'];
  $response[$i]['description']  = $row['description'];
  $response[$i]['rating']       = $row['rating'];
  $response[$i]['download']     = $row['download'];
  $response[$i]['buy']          = $row['buy'];
  $i++;
  }
mysql_close($con);

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

In your html file where you are getting this ajax response, I am giving you the hint how can u use this ajax response:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            data = '';
            $.each(response,function(i,val){
              data = '<div class="category-image">'+val.image+'</div>'+
            '<div class="category-link"><a href="#">'+val.id+'</a></div>'+
            '<div class="category-desc"><p>'+val.description+'</p> </div>'+
            '<div class="rating5" >'+val.rating+'</div>'+ 
            '<div class="category-download-btn"><a href="'+val.download+'">Download </a></div>'+
            '<div class="category-buy-btn"><a href="'+val.buy+'">Buy</a></div>';
            $('<div>').attr('id',i).html(data).appendTo('#response');
        });
            });
        }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='response'></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am getting this a little, i will try this method of yours.

Comment: using json is good because it gives you control modify the response data as per your requirement.

Comment: i shall check out and let you know

Comment: resolved it it was an extra }); at end, also tell me where to put sorting option in your code to work

Comment: see i have shown you, that how ajax can send JSON data and how to access these json data. The way I have created div tables same way you can create table which you implement earlier and you can sort.

Answer (score 0):

if you wan to pull the result in these divs then use same divs instead of table/tr/tds or you can bind it by receiving json/xml or any kind of object based data